# Xcode project add video file and delete after use

Tags: ios, objective-c, video

I have Xcode project with added to target video file: [image: app]

I see this file in my Xcode left panel, like this: [image]

So, I can take path for this video file like `[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:videoName withExtension:videoExtension]`.

But I wanna delete this video, after playback, but, `[NSBundle mainBundle]` is readonly. So I cant delete this video.

How to use add video to Documents directory from Xcode project?
For taking path like this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Video.mp4"];
```

Comment: Why you need to delete that video from bundle ?

Comment: You can't do what you want. If you bundle the video with the app, you can't ever delete it.

Comment: @MidhunMP it just intro video, i don't need to keep it. How to add video file to project, and then delete, after playback? Only uploading video after installing app on device?

Comment: @rmaddy How to add video file to project, and then delete, after playback? Only uploading video after installing app on device?

Comment: If you don't want to bundle the video with the app and leave it there for the lifetime of the app then you either need to download it or play it remotely. Both require an Internet connection.